# How do I preserve the items order when filtering in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've order the `Recommendations` by the `rating_prediction` and get the ids, then when I filter it to get the `Tracks`, the order is not the same anymore

```
class RecommendationView(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = RecommendedTrackSerializer
    queryset = Recommendations.objects.all()
    pagination_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS

    def get_queryset(self):
        recommendation = Recommendations.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        sorted_recommendation = recommendation.order_by('-rating_prediction')
        ids = list(sorted_recommendation.values_list('track', flat=True))
        tracks = Track.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
        return tracks
```

models:

```
class Recommendations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='user which the recommendation is given',
    )
    track = models.ForeignKey(
        Track,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name="track which recommend to the user",
    )
    date = models.DateField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        verbose_name='when the recommendation was generated',
    )
    rating_prediction = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(5)]
    )

class Track(models.Model):
    track_id = models.CharField(max_length=24)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, through='Tagged', blank=True)
    similarity = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        blank=True,
        through='FusionSimilarity',
        related_name='similar_to',
        symmetrical=False
    )
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='PlayTrack', blank=True)
```

Comment: Well you do *not* order on the `Track`s, only on the `Recomendation`s. So you should order on the `rating_prediction` of the corresponding `recommendation`s. This is why you better write this with one query.

Comment: What exactly order isn't preserved? I believe that `ids` will have the correct order. `tracks` obviously will not be ordered since you haven't applied any ordering to the queryset.

Comment: I see, but how do I do that ?

Comment: I expect the tracks will be ordered as same as the ids I got when I order it in Recommendations

Comment: How are those two models related? Post your models please.

Comment: @EdwinHarly: no they are not, you simply ask the database for the `Track`s corresponding to these `ids`. The database has now the freedom to provide the tracks in any possible order. You thus need to force ordering.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see, I'll remember that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You filter like:

```
tracks = Track.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
```

But this does *not* mean that a the `Track`s are in the same order as the `ids`. You simply filter, and depending on how the database has indexed this, typically it will produce a list order by the `id`, or by some other metric (for example if you attached a default order to the `Track` model). This can depend on the database engine as well. Since you never state the order, the database thus has the "freedom" to pick any order.

You can however reduce the amount of querying, and write it like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Track.objects.filter(
        recommendations__user=self.request.user
    ).order_by('-recommendations__rating_prediction')
```

In case a user can only give one recommendation per track, this will not produce any duplicates. In case a user can give multiple recommendations for a track, you should add the `.distinct()` call.

We thus obtain `Track`s that were recommended by a given user, and we order these by how the user recommended these, all in *one* query.

Comment: I was amazed that `Track` could find its way to `Recommendations`, even when on the Track model has nothing related to `Recommendations`

Comment: @EdwinHarly: if you make a relation from one model to another, Django automatically makes a reverse relation. You can for instance for some `Track` object write `some_track.recommendations_set.all()`, this is a `QuerySet` containing *all* the recommendations for that `Track`. You can of course write more sophisticated queries as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
Track.objects.filter(recommendation__user=self.request.user).order_by('-recommendation__rating_prediction')
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while ago but I wanted to add a solution if your ordered list is not easily accessable through queryset methods.

You can build a conditional list to use if your list isn't too long. Like this:

```py
from typing import Any, List
from django.db.models import Case, When

def generate_sorting(ordered_list: List[Any], field_name: str) -> Case:
    conditions_list = []
    for index, field_value in enumerate(ordered_list):
        condition = {field_name: field_value}
        conditions_list.append(When(**condition, then=index))

    return Case(*conditions_list, default=len(conditions_list))


ids = list(sorted_recommendation.values_list('track', flat=True))
id_sorting = generate_sorting(ids, "id")

"""
this will return something like this:
>>> generate_sorting([12, 3], "id")
id_sorting = Case(When("id"=12, then=0), When("id"=3, then=1), default=2)
"""

tracks = Track.objects.filter(id__in=ids).order_by(id_sorting)
```